# How to construct circle that tanget to one to three line segments and go through one to two points?

Tags: geometry

I need three equations (algorithms) for finding circle that:

1. Tangent to three line segments.
2. Tangent to two line segments and a point.
3. Tangent to line segment and two points.
   Or it is need to show that such circle are impossible to construct.

In firts case I have a three line segments: [A1, B1], [A2, B2], [A3, B3]. And I want to check, does it possible to construct a circle that tuch all of them or not. And if it does,I need an eauation for such circle.

The other cases are the same.

Comment: Could you show own efforts? SO is not right place to ask smbdy to make homeworks.

Comment: It is not a homework. It is a task that could be solved for constructing Voronoi diagram inside a simple polygon.

Answer (score 1):

Write line equations in normal form

```
ai*x + bi*y + ci = 0  (where ai^2+bi^2=1)
```

Make linear equation system

```
(a2-a1)*cx + (b2-b1)*cy = c1-c2
(a3-a1)*cx + (b3-b1)*cy = c1-c3
```

and solve it to get incircle center coordinates `cx, cy`.

Then substitute these coordinates in the first line equation to get circle radius

```
R = abs(a1*cx + b1*cy + c1)
```

Note that changing signs in coefficients differences, we can get 3 more solutions - for cases of outer circles touching all three lines.

P.S. There is rule about **one** question per theme

Comment: @Ivan Z Is my answer unclear?